# How to add description on each category in Core Plot

Tags: core-plot

I've developed a graph for Mac OSX in Xcode5 using Core Plot it looks like this

[image]

but in the core plot examples it shows a graph with description of the value on each category like this:

[image]

I want to do something similar with each period, I want to add on the top the value like this:

abr 14 = 1500, may 14 = 0

for being more specific, how to do that???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add data labels to one of the plots (probably the one with the red line). Set the `labelFormatter` and `labelTextStyle` to turn the labels on and `labelOffset` and `labelRotation` to adjust the position and rotation.